# how to fix "Slider tick start and end position without any space" in UWP

Tags: uwp, slider

In UWP, Slider TickBars take extra space from start and end. I want it to be aligned with start and end edge of a slider.
how to fix "Slider tick start and end position without any space" in UWP?

[image: vertical bar (start & end) takes some space with slider]

Set slider with a TickFrequency in xaml. In TickBar Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3".

```
in xaml:
<Slider Style="{StaticResource CustomSlider}" 
    RelativePanel.Below="NarrowText"
    Width="404"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="3"
    TickFrequency="1"
    TickPlacement="Outside"
    ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"
    Value="{x:Bind _viewModel.SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Slider>

in style:
<TickBar 
    x:Name="TopTickBar" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    Grid.RowSpan="3" 
    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}" 
    Height="14" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Visibility="Visible"
/>
```

I want that slider start and end edge should be aligned (same position) with tickbar(rectangle).

Applying margin in TickBar causes alignment mismatch with thumb.
[Thumb in 1st position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ySen.png)
[Thumb in 2nd position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyF2k.png) [Thumb in 3rd position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTEuC.png) [Thumb in 4th position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NGQ.png)

Comment: Does the following answer work ?

Comment: Applying margin in TickBar causes alignment mismatch with thumb. You can check the images in my question. I have modified my question. How to fix it?

Comment: 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ySen.png  2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyF2k.png 3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTEuC.png 4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NGQ.png

Answer (score 0):

> how to fix “Slider tick start and end position without any space” in UWP

If you want to fix slider tick start and end position with out any space, you need to re-write slider style and edit `TopTickBar` ,`BottomTickBar`,`HorizontalInlineTickBar` margin, please refer the following style segment.

```
<TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
Visibility="Collapsed"
Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
Margin="-4,0,-4,4"
Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
<TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
Visibility="Collapsed"
Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
Grid.Row="1"
Margin="-4,0,-4,0"
Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
<TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar"
Visibility="Collapsed"
Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Margin="-4,4,-4,0"
Grid.Row="2"
Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

And for your scenario, you could only modify `TopTickBar` style like the follow

```
<TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
Visibility="Collapsed"
Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
Height="14"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
Margin="-4,0,-4,-8"
Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

[image]

Comment: After applying margin, thumb position mismatches with the tickbar position.
1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ySen.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyF2k.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTEuC.png
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NGQ.png
how to fix this?

Comment: I checked the screenshot, and set the `Margin` property for  `Thumb`, but it is hard to set correct position. The better way is make `Thumb` as thin rectangle. Too thin to  accurate.